# How to filter the data and display within static HTML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I am working on filtering the data and displaying the result within html container according to the value user selects from drop down menu. I am able to take the selected values but not able to proceed after, like how to query the selected value within html data and display the result accordingly. JSFiddle below for quick reference. Thanks in advance for any help/guidance.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTGz9/)

**jQUERY**

```
function filterData(select1, select2, select3, select4){
           select1 = $("#business option:selected").text();
           select2 = $("#geography option:selected").text();
           select3 = $("#technology option:selected").text();
           select4 = $("#strategy option:selected").text();
  alert('a - ' + select1 + '; b - ' + select2 + '; c - ' + select3 + '; d - ' + select4);

};
$("#searchBtn").on("click", function(){
  filterData();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updated fiddle below. You will have to work on validation part.. ie. if user doesn't select any value etc..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTGz9/4/)

```
$(".ui-list li").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(select1, "i")) < 0 && $(this).text().toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(select2, "i")) < 0 && $(this).text().toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(select3, "i")) < 0 && $(this).text().toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(select4, "i")) < 0){
      $(this).fadeOut();  
    } else{
      $(this).fadeIn();   
    }
  })           
}
```

Comment: thanks Nitesh. this is what I wanted to move further.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write HTML in any Div or other  tag.

Then you need to use to write HTML code as:

```
      var htmldata = $("#selectboxid option:selected").text();
```

Below Code Used for write HTML  if div already contain other html tags you need to first empty the html then use this code

```
         $("#divid").empty();
         $("#divid").html(htmldata);
```

Comment: @ Rahul...read the question carefully....Question is not about to add HTML.... it's about fitlering the data whithin existing html

Comment: Thanks Rahul, can you edit the JSfiddle and add your approach, I am unable to implement your logic.